# Count up javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

Its now showing secont counter up timer

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>    

<script type="text/javascript">

function CountUp(initDate,id){
    this.beginDate = new Date(initDate);
    this.numOfDays = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];
    var currYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    if ( (currYear % 4 == 0 && currYear % 100 != 0 ) || currYear % 400 == 0 ) {
        this.numOfDays[1] = 29;
    }
    this.borrowed = 0, this.years = 0, this.months = 0, this.days = 0;
    this.hours = 0, this.minutes = 0, this.seconds = 0; 
    this.calculate();
    this.update(id);
}

CountUp.prototype.datePartDiff=function(then, now, MAX){
    var temp = this.borrowed;   
    this.borrowed = 0;
    var diff = now - then - temp;
    if ( diff > -1 ) return diff;
    this.borrowed = 1;
    return (MAX + diff);    
}

CountUp.prototype.formatTime=function(){
    this.seconds = this.addLeadingZero(this.seconds);
    this.minutes = this.addLeadingZero(this.minutes);
    this.hours = this.addLeadingZero(this.hours);
}

CountUp.prototype.addLeadingZero=function(value){
    return (value + "").length < 2 ? ("0" + value) : value;
}

CountUp.prototype.calculate=function(){
    var currDate = new Date();
    var prevDate = this.beginDate;
    this.seconds = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getSeconds(), currDate.getSeconds(), 60);
    this.minutes = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getMinutes(), currDate.getMinutes(), 60);
    this.hours = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getHours(), currDate.getHours(), 24);
    this.days = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getDate(), currDate.getDate(), this.numOfDays[currDate.getMonth()-1]);
    this.months = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getMonth(), currDate.getMonth(), 12);
    this.years = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getFullYear(), currDate.getFullYear(),0);   
}

CountUp.prototype.update=function(id){
    if ( ++this.seconds == 60 ) {
        this.seconds = 0;
        if ( ++this.minutes == 60 ) {
            this.minutes = 0;
            if ( ++this.hours == 24 ) {
                this.hours = 0;
                if ( ++this.days == this.numOfDays[(new Date()).getMonth()-1]){
                    this.days = 0;
                    if ( ++this.months == 12 ) {
                        this.months = 0;
                        this.years++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.formatTime();  
    var countainer = document.getElementById(id);
    countainer.innerHTML ="<strong>" + this.years + "</strong> <small>years</small> <strong>" +
        this.months + "</strong> <small>months</small><strong> " + this.days + 
        "</strong> <small>days</small> <strong>" + this.hours + "</strong> <small>hours</small> <strong>" + 
        this.minutes + "</strong> <small>minutes</small> <strong>" + this.seconds +
        "</strong> <small>seconds</small>.";
    var self=this;
    setTimeout(function(){self.update(id);}, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div>
<div id="counter" >Contents of this DIV will be replaced by the timer</div>
<script type="text/javascript">new CountUp('April 04, 2010 13:11:20','counter');</script>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<div id="counter" >Contents of this DIV will be replaced by the timer</div>
<script type="text/javascript">new CountUp('April 04, 2012 13:11:20','counter');</script>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And how to change to like->

```
<div id="counter" countup='April 04, 2012 13:11:20'><div>
```

Comment: Two different elements sharing the same id, not sure how well that will work.

Comment: Your question is unclear,  Can you cut your code down to form a more minimal example, show an example of what is currently happening and a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please learn to ask proper questions. You haven't provided a concise and understandable problem statement. We shouldn't have to read through all your code just to guess what problem you are having

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o5gsx0fx/1/

I only wanted... Elements in span not in js. (Change elements from js to div)

Answer (score 1):

as Compass already commented you are using the same id for both div elements for the counters.

Depending on your browser getElementById gives you just something with this id. In your case it seems to always be the first, so the second never gets used.